# My HTML encoded file hyperlinks display files in Firefix but open Finder if clicked from Safari?

Tags: html, macos, safari

I am having a weird little problem with hyperlinks. I've been adding hyperlinks to a .html file using the obvious convention:

`<a href="Files/genome.fasta>My Genome</a>`

This file, `genome.fasta`, is a plain text file with the `.fasta` extension (common in biology). When I browse the .html file in firefox or chrome, I can click on the link and it loads the text file in the web browser, as wanted. Same for chrome.

However, in Safari, clicking the link doesn't open the file in the web browser, but instead opens Finder and highlights the file's location, which is not what I want. Is there anything I can do to the .html file to prevent Safari from using Finder? I want other people to being able to Safari with this file and not have to modify anything.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I suggest using another extension?

Comment: Unfortunately, these extensions are important and cannot be changed

Comment: M, do this: Do you know PHP? Check if the user is using safari, if yes, show them a message saying that they need to use Chrome or some other compatible browser.

Comment: haha, thanks for the thought. That is one way to tackle the issue. I was hoping for some command that would force Safari to display the linked file instead of triggering Finder

Comment: The problem is, safari and IE suck. #ChromeandFirefox for life.

Comment: Seriously take my suggestion. If you want I will reply you the source. :)

Comment: Anyone have a way to accomplish this within safari?